# Integrating the JavaScript into WordPress

Tags: post, button, download, wordpress-theming

I am trying to add a download button which re-directs to the default download page. Where there is timer and download link.

That same default download page works on all post downloads

As far as I know it is a basic thing, but as I am unaware of the correct term I am not able to understand how it is done. Kindly provide the steps or any online resources from where I can learn about it.

I have zero knowledge in coding. I checked on the internet and gpt to customize website. I am unable to find how to integrate this on post. I tried to check other website which has that option and tried asking GPT, I didn't get any response.

GPT reply:

> To integrate the given JavaScript snippet into your WordPress website
> and effectively ask a question on Stack Overflow for further
> assistance, follow these steps:
>
> Integrating the JavaScript into WordPress Identify Where to Place the
> Script: Decide whether the script should be added globally (on every
> page) or only on specific pages.
>
> Use a Child Theme or Custom Plugin: To avoid losing changes on theme
> updates, use a child theme or a custom plugin.
>
> Add the Script:
>
> Through functions.php: If you're using a child theme, add the script
> to the functions.php file using wp_enqueue_script for external scripts
> or wp_add_inline_script for inline scripts. Custom Plugin: Create a
> simple plugin to add your custom JavaScript. Handle baseURL and link:
> Ensure that baseURL and link variables are defined correctly in your
> script. If they're dynamic, you'll need to set their values in PHP and
> pass them to your JavaScript.
>
> Example Code for functions.php:
>
> ````
>     wp_enqueue_script('custom-enroll-script', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/custom-enroll.js', array(),
> false, true);
>
>     // If baseURL and link are dynamic, set them here and pass to script
>     $script_data = array(
>         'baseURL' => 'your_base_url_here',
>         'link'    => 'your_link_here'
>     );
>     wp_localize_script('custom-enroll-script', 'scriptParams', $script_data); } add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts',
> 'custom_enqueue_scripts'); ```
>
> In this example, replace 'your_base_url_here' and 'your_link_here'
> with the actual values. The JavaScript file (custom-enroll.js) should
> contain your script, modified to use scriptParams.baseURL and
> scriptParams.link.
> ````

Comment: Got it, today is my first day here.

Comment: Can anyone kindly give answer on how do I add download button on mulitple post and it re-direct to default download page and automatically select the source post download link.